# How to set name of columns from rows values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-extraction, data-wrangling

how can I set up the column name as shown in the picture attached?
I have joined multiple dfs but generates non-representative names for the columns.

```
dfs= 
[data_3,data_4,data_5,data_6,data_7,data_8,data_9,data_11,data_12,data_13,data_14]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='date'), dfs)
df_final.set_index('date')
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pe0F.png)
[image]

Comment: Something like `dfs.columns = dfs.loc["2014-01-01", :]`

Comment: what names do you want to set up. May be try something like `new_dfs = [i.rename(columns = dict(zip(i.columns.difference(['date']),i.columns.difference(['date']).columns + f"_dfno_{e}")) for e,i in enumerate(dfs,3)]` and then try using `new_dfs ` in `reduce`?

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it returns: 'Index' object has no attribute 'columns'. I guess we should put as the original sintax something like this: i.rename(columns={'oldname':'newname'}) ?? but I do not know how to implement this with your solution..

Comment: apologies i had a typo, try `new_dfs = [i.rename(columns = dict(zip(i.columns.difference(['date']),i.columns.difference(['date']) + f"_dfno_{e}")))
for e,i in enumerate(l,3)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments  , you can rename the columns in the dataframes based on an enumerator:

```
new_dfs = [i.rename(columns = 
dict(zip(i.columns.difference(['date']),i.columns.difference(['date']) + f"_dfno_{e}"))) 
     for e,i in enumerate(dfs,3)]
```

Then try this under `reduce`:

```
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='date'), new_dfs )
df_final.set_index('date')
```